# Getting error installing Provisioning Profile on mac

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I am having a Xamarin forms ios app with push notifications enabled it works fine with a Distribution provisioning profile but not with the Development profile. I have uploaded the certificates for Development and Distribution in the Identifier of my app on apple account. Now when I am downloading and installing the profile which is using that App ID(Identifier) I am getting the below error every time:

> Failed to install one or more provisioning profiles on this device.
>
> Please ensure the provisioning profile is configured for this device.
>   If not, please try to generate a new profile.

I am getting this error on installing every profile.
mac version is 10.15.4 and Xcode 11.4 (11E146).

I have tried the Download Manual Profiles option in Xcode preferences for my account.
Please help me with fixing this blocker !!

Comment: Can you clear the existing profiles and redownload again in mac

Comment: Open this path in finder and clear all provisioning profiles

Comment: ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/

Comment: Then redownload all

Comment: Can you post the solution below and mark it as answer to help others ?

Answer (score 5):

I even didn't have any provisioning profiles with the same uuid, but copying it manualy did the job. This is my example:

```
   cd ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles

   cp ~/Downloads/YourAppsProvProf.mobileprovision ./2a3cbed1-dbfc-42c8-8ac6-54c10f1d99a0.mobileprovision
```

(I've replaced uuid with fake one to avoid providing real data on stackoverflow. You need to select provisioning profile in finder and switch finder to column view, then you can see profile's details, eg. its uuid)

Comment: This worked for me when nothing else did

Comment: If above url does not work, use following: 

~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning

Answer (score 3):

I also experience the same issue and I am not in a situation to delete all provisioning profiles (in ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/)

Instead I deleted the old profile with same uuid (You can open a provisioning profile in TextEdit and find UUID or Just tap space mac will Show quick display with all details)

Then I downloaded the new profile, rename with uuid of the new profile (.mobileprovision) and then copy to provisioning profiles folder (~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/)

Then I am able to select the profile in Xcode and use it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by removing all previous profiles that were in my `downloads` folder. I simply deleted these profiles and restarted my Mac.
Everything worked fine.

I faced this issue with my Flutter setup.